# Power consumption in photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

If I always want to keep plate A negatively charged and plate B positively, how much does the battery have to consume?(maintaining a constant flow of photo-electrons)

as electrons are removed from plate A it becomes positive and plate B negative, and I want them to remain negative and positive respectively
[image]

Comment: Well, the power supply will need to provide some current at some voltage, correct?

Comment: yes, consider initially the plates are charged

Comment: So, you have a current at a voltage...